# Android MenuItem.getItemId returns integer values

Tags: android, menuitem

I have a problem in my Android project trying to make a options menu.

When I debug/execute my app and click over the menu-button, ALWAYS R.id.btnInfo attribute returns an integer, not the menu item id (btnInfo).

Here is the code:

Menu declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/btnInfo"
      android:title="@string/btnInfo"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_info" />
</menu>
```

Loading menu:

```
/**
 * Options Menu Inflater Event
 */
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.options, menu);
   return true;
 }
```

Click Event:

```
/**
 * Click on Options Menu Button
 */
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
   case R.id.btnInfo:
     // To-do:
     return true;
   default:
     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct behaviour.

Check the `R.java` file, for each item you give an ID, it generates an integer ID to refer too.

Example:

```
public static final class menu {
    public static final int option1=0x7f0a0000;
    public static final int option2=0x7f0a0001;
    public static final int option3=0x7f0a0002;
}
```

Comment: so....if this is my R.java:

    public static final class id {
        public static final int btnInfo=0x7f060007;
        public static final int btnSimulate=0x7f060003;


the correct code will be:

       /**
        * Click on Options Menu Button
        */
...
          switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case : 0x7f060007
             // To-do:
...

???

Is....really strange. I suppose that I´m a bit confused xD
What I have to do to use case: case R.id.btnInfo and the Id of the buttom?

Thx!!

Comment: You have the correct code already. `case R.id.btnInfo`, means if your btnInfo is pressed, run that piece of code. Your code is fine!

Comment: The number generated will change when you add / remove ids so reference it from the generated variable (R.xxx.xxxx) - the code you posted in your question is correct

Comment: but do not work!....if I debug my app the switch do not execute the code in the case.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've fixed this yet, but you'd want code in the case statement if you're debugging or it might jump it (I'm not sure). Just add logging there and see if it gets hit. Your code is right, it may be worth doing Project > Clean.

Comment: something strange is happend in my project. Right now the code in the case IS Executed....but I promisse that a few minutes ago no...I am going to re-create all the project to be sure of everything is allright